# Customize product detail page TABS

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, rwd

I customize the tabs on product detail page. I created an attribute on the admin code it like this

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">

<dl class="collateral-tabs" id="collateral-tabs">

<!--  First tab  **********************    -->

    <dt class="tab"><span>Description</span></dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content">    
            <h2>Details</h2>
            <div class="std">
                <?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>

    <!--  Second tab  **********************    -->
    <dt class="tab"><span>Specification</span></dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="specification" class="std">
                <?php echo $_product->getSpecification() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>

    <!--  Third tab  **********************    -->
    <dt class="tab"><span>Delivery</span></dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="delivery" class="std">
                <?php echo $_product->getDelivery() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>

    <!--  Fourth tab  **********************    -->
    <dt class="tab"><span>Reviews</span></dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="customer-reviews" class="std">
                <p class="no-rating"> <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>


</dl>
```

But what happen is, the images is not loading. I used WYSIWYG editor for description, specification and delivery tab.

I think I'm missing something? I'm using RWD theme on Magento Enterprise edition version 1.9

Please help.

Hope and appreciate your answers

Answer (score 1):

INstead of `echo $_product->getDescription()` try this:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription, 'description');
```

If it works do the same for `delivery` and `specifications`.

Comment: Hi Marius,
Thanks for your reply. I tried your code but its not working. Any other way?

Comment: Define "not working". You also have to allow media directives in product attributes. For that go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend` and set the flag `Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories` to `Yes`.

Comment: Hi. I already did it. I found out the template calling is not all in the theme directory hence it is on the other theme for example on the base theme. I just copy it and rename it to my desire tab.Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @AlyssaReyes. In this case please add what you found as an answer and mark it as accepted.